# Remotely send music to Android device

Tags: music, remote-control

There are multiple questions in *Android Enthusiasts* addressing the possibility of streaming music to an Android device, *where the point of control is the said device.*

I need something slightly different.  Suppose when I come home, I plug my Android device on my stereo system, and work on my laptop.  Now, I want to play an mp3/webradio/the sound of a movie/white noise in my stereo system, using my Android device while not moving from my chair.  What are the softwares to do so?

Simply put: I want to beam sound through wifi, to my Android device, from **and controlled by** my laptop.  The only solution I can think of is to open a tunnel to the Android sound device and ask my playing software to send the sound to it.

*Technical details*: Tablet Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1; Laptop with Linux.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Asking for recommendations are off-topic, please read the [FAQ] :) In relation to the answer below by @LiamW, that software, in which the answerer failed to mention has the following *Before using SoundWire on your Android device you must install and run the SoundWire Server application on the Windows/Linux PC or laptop which is your source of music, web audio streaming, or other sounds*, also, its not "free" per-se, rather a trial.. *The free version of the application identifies itself by voice every 45 minutes and displays ads. There is a 10 minute compression trial in the free version.*

Comment: @t0mm13b: My very bad.  I didn't check the FAQ, and saw a few "what's the app for X" questions, thinking it was OK.  We should close this question as off-topic to not give a bad example, though.

Comment: Maybe I am blind, but where does this question ask for an App as solution? I see no reason to close it.

Comment: Well, not to insist on having my own question closed, but I do ask, in plain terms, "What are the softwares to do so?"; this is the only actual question in the text.  But definitely your call, mod.

Answer (score 5):

I am practically certain that the [soundwire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree) app will do what you want it to do (if I have it the right way around).

Comment: Thanks a lot; I'm playing with it right now, it seems to precisely do what I need.  Curious how I missed it in my numerous searches.

Answer (score 0):

It requires setting up a semi-server app on your laptop, but you could do this with the Logitech Squeezebox software.

Install the (free) server software onto your laptop from here: http://www.mysqueezebox.com/download

This will index all of the media on your laptop and give you a web based interface to your library.

Then you can use something like the [SqueezePlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.bluegaspode.squeezeplayer) app on your phone to connect to the server and play what you nominate.

Comment: Thanks!   Am I mistaken in thinking that this requires action *from the device* rather than from the workstation?  This is precisely what I want to avoid.  Plus, I want to stream any sound, not my library.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Other than starting the Squeezeplayer app, you don't do anything on the device. In the web interface (which your laptop's web browser can connect to) you can select songs from your library, playlists, pick a streaming radio station, or pick a streaming service like Last.fm or Spotify. You can see some of the streaming services, apps and plugins it supports here http://www.mysqueezebox.com/index/Home If you want to stream whatever sound would otherwise be playing through your laptop's speakers (eg current movie) use the WaveInput plugin http://wiki.slimdevices.com/index.php/WaveInput_plugin